# USB drive detected but no device created

Tags: usb

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 inside a VirtualBox VM (with macOS 11.6.2 as the host).

I have an SSD in a USB external drive enclosure (SIIG ASMT1053 USB 3.0 to SATA 2.5" Enclosure), connected to the host. I've gone through the steps to ensure VirtualBox passes the USB device through to the Ubuntu guest.

When I connect the USB device to the host, it is detected by the Ubuntu guest. However, no entry is created under /dev (e.g. /dev/sdb), so I can't partition or mount it.

I'd appreciate any help determining why no device is created, and figuring out how I can format, partition, and mount this drive.

Logs from `dmesg` after connecting the device:

```
[   51.495253] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   51.518957] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   51.518960] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[   51.518961] usb 2-1: Product: ASMT1053
[   51.518963] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: asmedia
[   51.518964] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 123456789012
[   51.540988] usb 2-1: UAS is blacklisted for this device, using usb-storage instead
[   51.540992] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   51.541138] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
[   51.541167] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[   51.545275] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   51.577561] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   52.687929] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   52.856207] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   73.623120] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

Output of `lsblk` after the drive is attached:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 43.1M  1 loop /snap/certbot/1670
loop1                       7:1    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1270
loop2                       7:2    0 99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11993
loop3                       7:3    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2284
loop4                       7:4    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop5                       7:5    0 70.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21029
loop6                       7:6    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop7                       7:7    0 43.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14295
loop8                       7:8    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
sda                         8:0    0   20G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   19G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   10G  0 lvm  /
  ├─ubuntu--vg-lv--0      253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─ubuntu--vg-lv--1      253:2    0    7G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
sr1                        11:1    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Output of `lsusb` with the drive attached - the first entry is the external drive enclosure:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. Name: ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `usb-devices` with the drive attached - the first entry is the external drive enclosure:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 8
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.4.0-94-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:0c.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=80ee ProdID=0021 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=VirtualBox
S:  Product=USB Tablet
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=05.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.4.0-94-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:0c.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=174c ProdID=55aa Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=asmedia
S:  Product=ASMT1053
S:  SerialNumber=123456789012
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=144mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The drive enclosure wasn't getting enough power. The USB cable from the enclosure splits into two cables; I had to plug them *both* into separate USB slots on my MacBook before the drive would power up and appear (as /dev/sdb, in my case).

I'm assuming the narrower of the two cables is for extra power, so I plug it in first.

Updated `dmesg` output after re-trying with the second cable attached:

```
[ 5021.219010] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 5021.240592] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 5021.240595] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 5021.240597] usb 2-1: Product: ASMT1053
[ 5021.240599] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: asmedia
[ 5021.240600] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 123456789012
[ 5021.247710] usb 2-1: UAS is blacklisted for this device, using usb-storage instead
[ 5021.247713] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 5021.248012] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
[ 5021.248034] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 5022.278849] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     asmedia  ASMT1053         0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 5022.279259] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 5022.284137] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[ 5023.301539] ....ready
[ 5026.376180] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[ 5026.380215] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 5026.380219] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 5026.383386] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 5026.411042]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[ 5026.440616] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```